# Creating Pandas Dataframe row on the basis of other column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe having three column :

```
order_no  product  quantity
0         5bf69f    3
0         5beaba    2
1         5bwq21    1
1         5bf69f    1
```

I want to create row if quantity value is greater than 1 like this:

```
order_no   product  quantity
0          5bf69f   1
0          5bf69f   1
0          5bf69f   1
0          5beaba   1
0          5beaba   1
1          5bwq21   1
1          5bf69f   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First is necessary unique index values, so if necessary:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by column `quantity` and expand rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), set column to `1` by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last again create unique index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['quantity'])].assign(quantity=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   order_no product  quantity
0         0  5bf69f         1
1         0  5bf69f         1
2         0  5bf69f         1
3         0  5beaba         1
4         0  5beaba         1
5         1  5bwq21         1
6         1  5bf69f         1
```

Using `numpy.repeat` is possible, but numpy cast all data to object, because `string` column:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,df.quantity,axis=0)).dtypes)
0    object
1    object
2    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: or `pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,df.quantity,axis=0),columns=df.columns).assign(quantity=1)`

Comment: @anky_91 - there is problem if different columns types numpy set all of them to strings

Comment: i see, noted. :) Thanks.

Comment: I am getting error: TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: @souravkhanna - What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: (order        int64),
(_id         object),
(quantity    object)

Comment: @souravkhanna - so your first step before my solution is cast column to integer by `df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].astype(int)`